# diffirence between "i have no..." and "i've got no..."

Tags: word-choice, differences

Is there a diffirence between 'i have no evidence' and i've got no evidence'?

Comment: Diffirence? Both fail to capitalise 'I', both mean the same thing, the latter is more common in the UK than it is in the US, and is less formal.

Comment: There certainly *can* be a difference, yes. *I have (**possess**) no evidence* versus *I have got (**received**) no evidence*. However, *have got* can also be interpreted to mean the first.